# Find my current ranking based on points from a long list of users

Tags: mongoose

I got a huge table of users (10,000+) and I need to find out what your position is among all those users based on the point you (and everyone else) have.

My only solution is to read all users into a JS array and loop thru and count until I find you. It works but not a solid solution on the long term as users table grow.

Is there a smarter way to do this?

Here is an example user table

```
{
    "name"  : "aaa",
    "points": 12 
},
{
    "name"  : "bbb",
    "points": 32 
},
{
    "name"  : "ccc",
    "points": 52 
},
{
    "name"  : "eee",
    "points": 41 
},
{
    "name"  : "fff",
    "points": 23 
},
{
    "name"  : "foobar",
    "points": 35 
}
```

Lets say my name = "foobar" and I want to know how I rank compared to everyone else. 
(result here should be 3rd highest)

```
userModel.find().sort( { "points":-1 } )
```

and then loop thru all of them in JS, counting until I meet "foobar"
A real bummer if you are the 99999th :)

Any smart mongoose tricks which can do stuff like this?

Comment: no need to sort the whole table,first find your points,second loop array once to count how many user'points greater than yours.and eventualluy you will get O(1)

Comment: better with a red-black tree cache if the data changes offen while a normal tree will do the job if data do not change offen.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it

```
// How many users are in the user table
let totalUsers = 0;
await userModel.countDocuments({}, function( err, count){
    totalUsers = count;
})

// How many users have LESS points than me?
let lessUsers = 0;
await userModel.countDocuments({ "points": { $lte: userRecord.points } }, function( err, count){
    lessUsers = count;
})

// My position
let myPosition = totalUsers - lessUsers;
```

Turns out MongoDBs countDocuments is really fast!
Even with 100,000 users I couldnt even measure the time it takes to complete.